# jQuery bind function on touchmove not working?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am working on an AngularJS image viewer app where you can also draw ("annotate") on the images if you were in image edit mode. You enter the edit mode by clicking on a pencil icon which is the edit button. You close out of the edit mode by clicking another button, the close edit button.

Now annotations had a bug because of which the drawing action in edit mode interfered with the scroll event, and the view would start scrolling when you tried drawing something. So to fix that, I disabled scrolling while in the edit mode like so:

```
$('body').on("touchmove", function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```

And I would enable scrolling back when the close edit button was clicked like this:

```
$('body').off("touchmove");
```

This works fine, except for *some cases*, the view starts scrolling when I try to draw something *without having called the off function!* These cases are happening randomly and is not reliably reproducible, but when I sit with it for 5 minutes, doodling away, the unwarranted scroll happens every now and then.

I actually tested this by putting breakpoints on all occurrences of the off method - the breakpoints were not hit and yet the screen started scrolling.

Is the on/off method buggy? Is there a time limit involved? Help!

Answer (score 0):

[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) attaches an event handler to an element.

[`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) removes a «previously attached» event handler from an element.

So if you define the "handler" like this:

```
function preventTouch(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

And then call it on:

```
$('body').on("touchmove", preventTouch(e));
```

Then off:

```
$('body').off("touchmove", preventTouch(e));
```

It should work...
Try it!



You should probably also prevent these events: "touchstart" and "touchend" like so:

On:

```
$('body').on("touchmove touchstart touchend", preventTouch(e));
```

Off:

```
$('body').off("touchmove touchstart touchend", preventTouch(e));
```